# xmr-stak-cpu on Ubuntu 14.04 compilation issue

Tags: monerod-commands

I'm trying to install xmr-stak-cpu on Ubuntu 14.04 following steps described in the installation TXT file:
https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu/blob/master/LINUXCOMPILE.md

But executing `make install` i'm getting following output:

```
make install
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/crypto/c_skein.c.o
/usr/bin/c++filt: invalid option -- 'm'
Usage: /usr/bin/c++filt [options] [mangled names]
Options are:
  [-_|--strip-underscore]     Ignore first leading underscore
  [-n|--no-strip-underscore]  Do not ignore a leading underscore (default)
  [-p|--no-params]            Do not display function arguments
  [-i|--no-verbose]           Do not show implementation details (if any)
  [-t|--types]                Also attempt to demangle type encodings
  [-s|--format {none,auto,gnu,lucid,arm,hp,edg,gnu-v3,java,gnat}]
  [@<file>]                   Read extra options from <file>
  [-h|--help]                 Display this information
  [-v|--version]              Show the version information
Demangled names are displayed to stdout.
If a name cannot be demangled it is just echoed to stdout.
If no names are provided on the command line, stdin is read.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/crypto/c_skein.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmr-stak-c.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`cmake .` however uses `/usr/bin/c++` which was absent at my system and I had to create a sym link: c++ -> /usr/bin/gcc

```
/usr/bin/gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) 5.4.1 20160904
```

What can be done to install it?

Comment: Are you sure that a c++ compiler is installed on your system?
If it turns out not https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer. For some reason do not get notification about updates in the question. There is output of some commands following your link installing C++: https://pastebin.com/pCbuQM4Y
I have not done `sudo apt-get upgrade` as I afraid to break another things. I have added additional sources. Is it possible not to completely upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

c++ is the canonical "implementation independent" name for the platform's C++ compiler. gcc is the C compiler. g++ would be the C++ compiler. If you don't have g++ installed, then install it first. GCC supports many languages, but C++ may not be installed by default.

Looking at this repository, it seems to be using cmake and not normal makfiles, so once g++ install is done:

git clean -dfx
  cmake .
  make

should build it.

Comment: I have an error at the end of make install command. There are a lot of output. I copied it to the text file: https://pastebin.com/p76xkgpA